# grid is not binding in extjs6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

While trying to create a grid binding using model and store in extjs6, it is showing a blank page.
My code is below:

Model:

```
Ext.define('BillD', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'SlNo', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'BillNo', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'ItemCode', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Desc', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Qty', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Rate', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'DiscPercent', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'DiscAmt', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'Amount', type: 'float' }
    ]
})
```

Store:

```
var billDStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
           model: 'BillD',
           data: [{
                   SlNo: 1, BillNo: 123, ItemCode: 'Itm-003', Desc: 'Item 003', Qty: 2, Rate: 4, DiscPercent: 15, DiscAmt: 1, Amount: 7
               },{
                   SlNo: 2, BillNo: 543, ItemCode: 'Itm-133', Desc: 'Item 133', Qty: 10, Rate: 10, DiscPercent: 15, DiscAmt: 15, Amount: 85
               }]
       });
```

app.js :

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'ExtJSApp',
    launch: function () {
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
           renderTo: Ext.get('dvGrid'),
           store: billDStore,
           width: 1300,
           height: 200,
           title: 'dfssdf',
           columns: [
               {
                   text: 'SlNo',
                   width: 20,
                   sortable: false,
                   hideable: false,
                   dataIndex: 'SlNo'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Bill No',
                   width: 20,
                   dataIndex: 'BillNo',
                   hidden: true
               },
               {
                   text: 'ItemCode',
                   width: 50,
                   dataIndex: 'ItemCode'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Description',
                   width: 150,
                   dataIndex: 'Desc'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Quantity',
                   width: 100,
                   dataIndex: 'Qty'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Rate',
                   width: 100,
                   dataIndex: 'Rate'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Discount Percent',
                   width: 100,
                   dataIndex: 'DiscPercent'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Discount Amount',
                   width: 100,
                   dataIndex: 'DiscAmt'
               },
               {
                   text: 'Amount',
                   width: 100,
                   dataIndex: 'Amount'
               }
           ]
       });
 }
});
```

What I need to do to resolve my issue.?
Is there anything missing in my code? Especially any reference.?

Please help me...!!!

Thanks JChap...
It is not working in the Visual Studio for me. I am using the trial version. I think I missed some reference.But its working for me in the Fiddle.

I need to show one popup window to display the Item List. Also need to display the Item details in the billing grid after selecting it from this popup window. 
I tried to show a window from item code column of the grid, but nothing is happening. My code is in the Fiddle. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/186k

Please help me...

Comment: I see no issues with your code, https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1863 works fine.

Comment: Thanks JChap. That was my mistake. I define the model in a separate js file and refer it in the app.js by drag and drop. Now i moved the code to the same file and it showing the grid. So how we can refer one js file in to another in extjs.
Now I changed my code to set some columns as editable. but it is not working as expected. 
Please check the fiddle, 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/186k

Comment: In you fiddle replace renderTo: 'dvGrid' with renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

Comment: In your fiddle: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.